# MinGW's mingw-get fails downloading packages

Tags: mingw

I'm trying to set up MinGW. I have downloaded the latest installer, which installs mingw-get but this utility fails to fetch the packages and gives the following kind of messages:

> mingw-get: *** ERROR *** Get package: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/gcc-4.5.2-1-mingw32-lic.tar.lzma?download: download failed

There is no firewall running. Anyone had the same problem?

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has happened to me too and was due to - *I guess* - temporary problems to either the network or sourgeforge itself. **I suggest retrying after a while.**

Answer (score 4):

Try with "Administrator rights" . It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes from the network. I can't download it by using my fiber broadband microtalk communication bit it still downloading  by using my jio mobile network.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the file as an administrator, it should work

Answer (score -1):

Try installing it from osdn.net 
Here's the link: https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/releases/ 
It's same as sourceforge but was able to connect and download 
worked for me and my friends!