# I can't download minGW packages

Tags: c++, mingw

I am a windows 7 user.
I keep getting 'mingw-get-gui' error message while downloading minGW packages.
I've tried a lot of things but nothing seems to work, please help me.

[image: mingw-get-gui error message]

Comment: Sourceforge does not always work.

Comment: Is there a way to just download packages and moving them manually offline without web installers?

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291919/mingws-mingw-get-fails-downloading-packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291919/mingws-mingw-get-fails-downloading-packages)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW's mingw-get fails downloading packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291919/mingws-mingw-get-fails-downloading-packages)

Comment: *Is there a way to just download packages and moving them manually offline without web installers?* Well, yes, that's what the web installer does for you - if it doesn't work then the manual way won't work either. Unfortunately, Sourceforge is a dumpster fire and it baffless me why anyone still uses it, never mind a big project like MinGW.